# How can I connect my CDJ / DJM 2000 Nexus with Traktor?

Tags: software, dj, mixing, traktor

I would like to connect my CDJ / DJM 2000 Nexus with Traktor. How should I configure Traktor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Windows:

- Install CDJ drivers (and ideally update firmware): http://pioneerdj.com/english/products/player/cdj-2000nexus.html
- Connect the 2 CDJ 2000 through USB to your computer
- Start Traktor and configure as follow (tested with Traktor 2.6.3 and Traktor 2.6.5 with Windows 7 x64 Ultimate):

[image]

[image]

Not necessary (it should be automatically well configured), but in case of issue here is the mapping:

[image]

It should be working now. If needed, you can watch the [official Pioneer tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvdlIPPzhwA).

FYI hardware connections:

[image]

[image]